# How can I make iPhone X download all attachments automatically?

Tags: email, iphone, ios, mail.app

This is a recent issue that started on one of the latest iOS upgrades (now running 13.3). The built in Mail app won’t download attachments and often the text won’t be downloaded too. When I open an email message I have to click the Download button and wait. 
The “Load remote images” setting is set to on. I tried to remove and re-add the mail account. Nothing helps.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53927/how-can-i-force-ios-mail-to-download-the-entire-email-every-time?rq=1

Comment: Also IOS 13.3.1 is now out, so you might try upgrading. My IOS 13.3.1 always opens the complete email.